# Class that partly maps to Json type

Tags: c#, json.net

I have something like:

```
class ABC
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

And json like `{"name":"John","value":123}`

I want to parse this json and create an `ABC` for a specified `id` value. I wondered if I have to do this in two steps or can pass the `id` in somehow? Ideally these fields would be readonly but I'm not sure if JSON.net allows that.

e.g. a method like `ABC getABC(int id, string json)`

Comment: One option would be to implement a custom `JsonConverter` which upon creation also adds the `id`.

Comment: You can make the properties read-only but still deserializable by making them `private set` and adding a `[JsonProperty]` attribute.

Comment: Without knowing JSON.net well at all I'd say this sounds a great approach; might you expand it to a full answer @YuvalItzchakov?

Comment: @PsychomaticComplexity thanks for the `private set` tip I hadn't seen that before

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit code-golfy, but you want to make the members of `ABC` readonly, then deserialize JSON into an instance of `ABC` while passing in a specified `id` *using just one line of code*, you can do:

```
var abc = new JObject(new[] { new JProperty("id", id) }.Concat(JObject.Parse(json).Properties())).ToObject<ABC>();
```

Using the class:

```
class ABC
{
    readonly int m_id;
    readonly string m_name;
    readonly int m_value;

    public ABC(int id, string name, int value)
    {
        this.m_id = id;
        this.m_name = name;
        this.m_value = value;
    }

    public int id { get { return m_id; } }
    public string name { get { return m_name; } }
    public int value { get { return m_value; } }
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that, if an object has a single public parameterized constructor, Json.NET will invoke it to construct the object, matching argument names to JSON property names.  Thus you can pass the `id` in by parsing the JSON to a `JObject`, merging in the id, then deserializing to your final class.

A less code-golfy solution would be to do:

```
var abc = JObject.Parse(json).WithProperty("id", id).ToObject<ABC>();
```

Using the fluent extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JObject WithProperty(this JObject obj, string name, JToken value)
    {
        obj = obj ?? new JObject();
        obj[name] = value;
        return obj;
    }
}
```